# Passing two different types of data in a vector using interface

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, interface

In Actionscript3, as the title says, I'm trying to pass two different types of data in one vector through creating an interface for it. Does anybody have an example to do so?

Comment: how different are those 2 objects?

Comment: If BotMaster's comment is an inquiry into whether you should be putting disparate objects into a Vector at all, I agree that you should be very careful when hiding differences in an interface.  Unless you are locked down on why/how it will be done, since, now, and henceforth, your program can get very brittle.

Answer (score 2):

If they are unrelated objects, you might consider an Array instead.  If you want the features of a Vector, then you just treat it like usual: create a Vector with the interface as the type instead of the most common base class.

```
    var v:Vector.<IFace> = new Vector.<IFace>();
```

...and of course implement IFace on those classes you want to put into the Vector

UPDATE - OK, as an extension of the answer, here's an actual interface...

```
    public interface IFace
    {
        function doSomethingAllImplementersCanDo() : Boolean;
    }
```

...that would go in a file called IFace.as.  A class that implements IFace might look like this...

```
    public class MonsterTruck implements IFace
    {
        public function doSomethingAllImplementersCanDo() : Boolean
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

...and somewhere else in your program...

```
        var v:Vector.<IFace> = new Vector.<IFace>();
        var mt:MonsterTruck = new MonsterTruck();
        v.push( mt );
        var throughIFace:IFace = v.pop();
        trace( throughIFace.doSomethingAllImplementersCanDo() );
```

I recommend checking out Adobe documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html

Comment: hi joseph. thank you very much for your answer! i'm familiar with how i would have to implement the vector with the interface instead of the base class. what i don't know to do is how to write the interface. would you have an example? thank you!

Comment: @wolga, I'm not sure I quite understand.  How, on the one hand, do you know how to implement an interface, and on the other hand, not know how to write it?  How are you able to implement it without knowing how to write it?